# How to add my menu button in system bar in Android 3.1?

Tags: android, menu

My pad is SAMSUNG GT-P7510.I want to add a new menu in the system bar.But the menu shows in action bar.Like this:
[image]

But now it is like this:
[image]

It's in the right of top.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {     
    menu.add(0,0,1,"OK");
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Your current code for placing the menu item might be useful to determine the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my guess is you started off with a pre-honeycomb app and ran it on 3.*+ emulator.
it happens automatically if you use the right layout style/theme.
on eclipse just go to your layout and choose "android 3.0" on the top right corner.

hope it helps.

**EDIT:**
after you edited your question I understand i got your question wrong.
If I understand correctly you are just trying to show the menu item as a button outside the menu list and that's simple -
on the xml use the "showAsAction" option like so-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
         android:title="@string/menu_share"
         android:alphabeticShortcut='o'
         android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" /> 
</menu>
```

inflating it with

```
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.list_options_menu, menu);
```

or by code:

```
MenuItem item = menu.add("OK");
item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
```

Comment: yea sorry about that, I edited my answer after I saw your edit. check it out.

Comment: I use your method,but the menu item still shows on right of the top.I want to put the menu item into  system bar,like the "home" item.

Comment: @XX_brother the menu is automatically set to the bottom when the application layout is a pre-honeycomb layout and it is set to the top when its honeycomb and above. you shouldn't force it either way because that where the user will look for it. its like moving the minimize/maximize/close buttons on a windows application to the bottom.

Comment: OK.I finally understand what mean.Thanks very much.

Comment: The app which has a new menu item is pre-honeycomb,and it's compatible software.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove targetSdkVersion from manifest.xml file..

like from this format:

make it like:

Thanks,
Ram

Comment: from this format:
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
make it like:
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

Thanks,